# Does exercise really reduce stress in the biological meaning?

Tags: physiology, endocrinology, stress

It is a very [widespread claim](http://www.adaa.org/understanding-anxiety/related-illnesses/other-related-conditions/stress/physical-activity-reduces-st), that movement in general helps body to get out stress hormones. It is used as a warning for long sitting at the computer and I also heard it as a pro-vegan argument (*We receive stress hormones by eating cows which have no option to release it in the closed areas*).

How literal this rumour is?

Comment: With "... *helps body to get out stress hormones* ..." you mean to reduce the amount of stress hormones? Could you reference this "widespread" claim? In fact, strenuous exercise induces release of stress hormones. Without some sources to back this "claim" up this question may be opinion based. A more likely cause for stress hormones in meat may be the unpleasant last hours of these animal's lives spent in crowded cattle trucks and waiting for their deaths in the slaughter house.

Comment: @AliceD Yeah, the claim is just that they can not reliese it this way, unlike freely captive cattle.

Comment: I'd like to see sources as well.  I rarely see cows running in open areas like a field.

Comment: @Nathan I gave there a source for the stress release claim for human during exercise. I'm looking for the issue with captive cattle without movement now (but I just heard it  so it can take a while).

Comment: http://animalstudiesrepository.org/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1019&context=acwp_faafp Page 316

Comment: That link says exercise reduced stress, not that it reduces stress hormones.

Comment: @Nathan - I've lived in three countries across three continents and I have seen many, many cows in open fields O_o I don't know where you're at but, no, at Times Square you won't see any cattle grazing

Comment: @AliceD You can't say anything about the percent of cattle reared on huge open air areas because the closed ones aren't just avaiable for your sight. I'll try to find better links (unfortunately I won't have internet for next few days)

Comment: have a look at: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18787373

Answer (score 0):

Neurologically speaking, β-endorphin molecules (amongst other opioids) function to relieve pain or produce pleasurable feelings, thereby facilitating an individual to continue functioning in spite of injury or stress.<sup>[1]</sup>

β-Endorphin release in response to exercise has been known and studied since the 1980s.<sup>[2]</sup> Studies have demonstrated that serum concentrations of endogenous opioids, in particular β-endorphin, increased in response to both acute exercise and training.<sup>[2]</sup> The notion of β-endorphin release during exercise is colloquially known in popular culture as a runner's high.<sup>[3]</sup>

**tl;dr**: Yes, it has been shown that exercise can really reduce stress in the biological meaning.

[1] http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3104618/ 
[2] http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6091217 
[3] www.webmd.com/depression/guide/exercise-depression

Comment: Hm, that sounds trustful. But where do the stress hormones come to? Are they only beated by the amount of endorphin?

Comment: The question is not why exercise reduces stress, but reduces stress hormones.